# How to clear $HOME/.gradle/caches/ whenever I commit in git?

Tags: android, git, caching, gradle

How to clear  $HOME/.gradle/caches/ whenever I commit in git?

Is it possible for android studio to detect whenever something changes like git commit and would trigger clear gradle cache?

My main problem is that I have a script in `build.gradle`:

`def gitCommitCount = "git rev-list HEAD --count".execute().text.trim()`

These script will be used in naming my apk.

But the problem is , it wont update whenever I commit and the apk will install incorrectly using the previous apk version name. like `myapp-130.apk` and the new one is `myapp-131.apk` but the `myapp-130.apk` will be used instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your script is run after `git commit` is done. Is it possible to clear the cache in your script? If not, it could be done in a `post-commit` hook.

Touch a file named `post-commit` in .git/hooks/ and make it executable. It could be implemented like this in bash

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/cache/
```

By default, whenever a commit is made in the current repository, the hook is triggered.

Comment: wow thanks, I was actually reading post hooks now I know, but still im going to try this you already found out the solution im looking for thanks so much.